# Is there a limit of GPIOs that can be used in Linux?

Tags: linux, hardware, embedded, limit, gpio

When it comes to use GPIOs, is there a limited number that can be used in Linux (except through the limitation of the physical availability/amount of the ports/pins) or is it theoretically possible to use an infinite number of GPIOs in my program(s)?

Comment: If you had a chip with infinite GPIO pins, of course it would work.

Comment: Do you know this or were you guessing like me ? ;)

Comment: I'm being facetious (chips with infinite GPIO pins are mythical).  The answer to the question, "How many GPIO pins can the linux kernel access?" is probably: in general, *all of them*, although this presumably requires explicit support for the particular hardware.  I don't think there's much of a sensible answer that can be given to your question beyond that.  While in some contexts you can expand the number of pins (via, e.g., something on the I2C bus), I don't think you can do that into infinity anyway.

Comment: So you could call this an undefined behavior ? Like: in theory Linux can handle infinite GPIOs, but when it comes to reality too many unknown parameter could interfere.

Comment: If you look in the `Documentation` directory of the kernel source, there's a `gpio` directory with a few files in it.  Some of them are userland oriented, but some of them are intended as "a guide for GPIO chip drivers writers" -- i.e., there is no universal GPIO interface that just works generically with any chip.  They have to be implemented *per chip*.  So when it comes to reality, the first question is, "is there a linux GPIO driver for this chip?".  If the answer is yes, you could then start considering "how many pins can I use?" specifically in relation to that chip.

Comment: But in theory, I guess someone could manufacture a chip with a million pins and write a working linux driver for it, so in theory yeah, you could access as many as you want.

Comment: I would agree with goldilocks, they're effectively unlimited given you'll always have a finite number of them physically. There are other limitations in place, mainly the datatypes used to store the GPIO info which will also contribute to the limiting set of factors.

Comment: Alright I was looking for that confirmation of my opinion. Thank you for your help and time. I would close this thread, if there was an answer.